# Is Lua same strength as Java on Android, or are there any limitations?

Tags: java, android, lua

So I've been trying to get into Android app development and everywhere tutorials say that Java is a "main" language for android development. And I also found out that Lua can be used too. My question is, can Lua make apps of same grade as Java or should I rather learn Java?

The thing is, everything I've found mentions Lua as secondary language, and then also I found that Lua is easier to learn than Java, but that apps made using Corona SDK are mainly for games. So can normal apps be developed too, or should I head for Java?

What I mean to ask is if the apps made with LUA can be of just as good quality as apps made with Java or do only simpler and less advanced apps can be made with LUA? Basically what I meant was does LUA offer same functions and features when it comes to programming for android?

I would be making apps such as CCleaner, uTorrent, and not games.

I also have a background in C.

Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: Lua is mostly used as an extension to another language, for example for modular components.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, try both languages and take the one you're most comfortable with.

But, to answer you question, you can indeed make Android (and iOS, Windows Phone) apps using Corona SDK. Its UI library is very effective and will let you build every kind of app you'd want.

Another really interesting Lua framework is **LÖVE** (or Love2D). It's becoming more and more popular as a lot of people use it for game prototyping (jams) or even bigger projects (take a look at Wanderer on Kickstarter).

Although LÖVE only officially has Desktop builds (OS/X, Windows, Linux), its community made ports that allow you to export to a lot of other platforms as well. These include iOS, Android, Windows Phone, and even portable consoles like 3DS and PS Vita. You can write your app once and export to all these platforms.

LÖVE is made in C/C++, and is totally open-source. This said, if you have a C background, you'll be able to implement new features if you feel like something's lacking.

I highly recommend you to check it out on https://love2d.org

Comment: Problem is... the UI is very important but it's not everything in an app, so if an SDK (I'm talking generically here) lets me build wonderful tableviews but I can't make a PayPal payment (and my app needs this feature), I can't choose this SDK. This is a very broad question, it's not easy to reply, there are dozens of variables involved.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's all C behind. This lets you add every feature you feel like is missing, and you might be able to add Paypal support this way. Apart from that, I honestly don't think Paypal is supported by LÖVE, but you can make it work easily with Corona SDK : see https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/23854-paypal-integration-in-corona-app/

Comment: I was not talking about LOVE or Corona, but simply to verify what you can do before choosing   :-)   As far as I know, Corona SDK lets you do lots of interesting things if you own an Enterprise license (https://coronalabs.com/products/enterprise/)

Comment: Well that would be really awesome if I could fully build apps with C cause I don't have to learn new languages, I will make sure to check out that framework.

Comment: Lua is so easy to learn you'll never want to quit. And C/Lua is a winning combo.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not about if Lua provides the same functions and features. You should ask if CoronaSDK provides the same functions and features.

It's not about the language, but the framework.

Going native (Java) always has the best performance. CoronaSDK is a library built upon it. It does not have all the functions and features. Therefore, if you want to build apps of the same grade (performance/features) as native apps via CoronaSDK, you can't.

But it doesn't mean you can't make good apps via CoronaSDK because there are many things to be considered if an app is good.

I have been using CoronaSDK for almost 2 years, but now I am learning Swift to build native apps for iOS. The reason I am shifting to Swift is exactly the same as your concern. CoronaSDK cannot build apps with the same grade as native apps. There are many sophisticated features I need but CoronaSDK does not provide. And also, I want to have the best performance.

However, if I want to build 2D games, I still go with CoronaSDK because it does have the strength to build fast prototypes and for most games, CoronaSDK covers most of the features you need and you can build faster in general.

Therefore, if your main purpose is to build business apps, I would say go native (Java in your case). And if you want to build 2D games, CoronaSDK is a good choice. It's very easy to learn Lua and you can build games faster, at least in the beginning.